Updated Form Data Not Displaying Department Names - Refresh Required
I'm encountering an issue where the department names are not updating correctly in my Vue 3 application after a form submission. When I update the form, all the related data displays correctly, except for the department names. To see the updated department names, I have to manually refresh the page.
Here's a summary of the problem:
Description:
I have a Vue 3 component that fetches and displays a list of shift schedulers.
The shift schedulers are associated with departments, and I need to show the department names in the UI.
When updating a shift scheduler, the related data updates correctly, but the department names are missing until I refresh the page.
Code Snippets:
Data Fetching and Mapping:
onBeforeMount(async () => {
    try {
        isLoadingShiftSchedular.value = true;
        isLoadingDepartments.value = true;

        const getDepartment = await useApiFetch('/api/departments');
        if (!getDepartment.error.value) {
            departmentList.value = getDepartment.data.value.data;
            departmentMap.clear();
            departmentList.value.forEach(department => {
                departmentMap.set(department.user_departmentID, department.department_name);
            });

            const getShiftSchedular = await useApiFetch('/api/shiftschedular');
            if (!getShiftSchedular.error.value) {
                shiftSchedularList.value = getShiftSchedular.data.value.data;
                shiftSchedularList.value = shiftSchedularList.value.map(shift => ({
                    ...shift,
                    user_department_name: departmentMap.get(shift.user_departmentID) || 'Department name not found'
                }));
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    } finally {
        isLoadingShiftSchedular.value = false;
        isLoadingDepartments.value = false;
    }
});

Updating the Form:
const handleUpdate = async () => {
    isUpdateDialogVisible.value = false;
    isLoadingVisible.value = true;
    await useApiFetch("/sanctum/csrf-cookie");
    const payload = { ...form.value, status: form.value.status === 'Active' };
    const { data, error } = await useApiFetch("/api/shiftschedular/" + form.value.shift_schedularID, { method: "PATCH", body: payload });
    if (!error.value) {
        const getShiftSchedular = await useApiFetch("/api/shiftschedular");
        shiftSchedularList.value = getShiftSchedular.data.value.data;
        form.value = {};
        isLoadingVisible.value = false;
        successAlertMessage.value = data.value.message || 'Update successful!';
        successAlertVisible.value = true;
    } else {
        isLoadingVisible.value = false;
        errorAlertVisible.value = true;
        errorAlertMessage.value = error.value.message || 'An error occurred.';
    }
};


Template Binding:
<template #item.user_department="{ item }">
    <span>
        {{ item.user_department_name }}
    </span>
</template>


this is where i update the form,
   <!-- Update Form Dialog -->
    <VDialog v-model="isUpdateDialogVisible" persistent width="1100">
        <DialogCloseBtn @click="isUpdateDialogVisible = !isUpdateDialogVisible" />
        <VCard title="Update Shift Scheduler">
            <VCardText v-if="isLoadingUpdateVisible">
                <VSkeletonLoader class="mx-auto" type="text, actions" />
            </VCardText>
            <VCardText v-if="!isLoadingUpdateVisible">
                <VRow>
                    <VCol cols="12" md="8">
                        <VRow>
                            <VCol cols="12">
                                <VSwitch v-model="form.status" :label="form.status" true-value="Active"
                                    false-value="Inactive" />
                            </VCol>
                            <VCol cols="12">
                                <AppTextField v-model="form.name" label="Name" />
                            </VCol>
                            <VCol cols="12">
                                <AppDateTimePicker v-model="form.shift_start" label="Shift Start" placeholder="Time"
                                    :config="{ enableTime: true, noCalendar: true, dateFormat: 'H:i' }" />
                            </VCol>
                            <VCol cols="12">
                                <AppDateTimePicker v-model="form.shift_end" label="Shift End" placeholder="Time"
                                    :config="{ enableTime: true, noCalendar: true, dateFormat: 'H:i' }" />
                            </VCol>
                            <VCol cols="12">
                                <AppSelect v-model="form.user_departmentID" :items="departmentList" label="Department"
                                    placeholder="Select Department" />
                            </VCol>
                        </VRow>
                    </VCol>
                    <VCol cols="12" md="4">
                        <VCard class="pa-3" outlined>
                            <!-- Label for Color Picker -->
                            <div class="mb-2">
                                <span class="font-weight-medium">Select Department Color</span>
                            </div>
                            <v-color-picker label="Chips" v-model="form.color" elevation="15" />
                        </VCard>
                    </VCol>
                </VRow>
            </VCardText>
            <VCardText v-if="!isLoadingUpdateVisible" class="d-flex justify-end flex-wrap gap-3">
                <VBtn variant="tonal" color="secondary" @click="isUpdateDialogVisible = false">
                    Close
                </VBtn>
                <VBtn :disabled="isLoadingVisible" @click="handleUpdate">
                    Save
                </VBtn>
            </VCardText>
        </VCard>
    </VDialog>

Expected Behavior:
After updating a shift scheduler, the department names should display correctly without needing to refresh the page.
Actual Behavior:
The department names are not updated until I manually refresh the page.
What I've Tried:
I've confirmed that the department names are being fetched and mapped correctly before the update.
I've verified that the updated shiftSchedularList includes the correct department names, but they do not appear in the UI until a page refresh.
Im lost now and not sure how to resolve this, im still new to programming and learning as i go

Where do you change the department name in your code? as far as I see, they are only set onBeforeMount.

@GertB. I have just updated the code

You didn't show how shiftSchedularList is used. Make sure there are no errors in console because they could prevent reactive data to update a view in normal way. Please, provide a way to reproduce, live demo would help. Api requests could be replaced with async dummy data. The code is complex enough and the way it works may rely on the way third-party lib behaves. Is it Vuetify? The question doesn't mention this. So the problem shouldn't be expected to be solved on paper.
